# Difference between now and future date as x day , y hours , z minutes via php Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'm using **laravel 5.5** and **Carbon** DateTime Library and have a future date and want to display difference between that time and Now.

But note that I want to display differences as this format :

```
x day , y hours , z minutes
```

that shows how many days, hours and minutes is left to that future date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `diff()` method and `d`, `h` and `i` properties like this:

```
$diff = $date->diff(now());

{{ $diff->d . ' days, ' . $diff->h . ' hours, ' . $diff->i . ' minutes' }}
```

http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Answer (score 1):

You can read the documentation here regarding everything with difference between dates:

[PHP Date difference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)